# Help check my pcb layout and routing please

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

This is my first time fabricating a simple PCB.
Could you help check for any mistakes in my PCB layout and routing?

[image]

[image]

- The power line is 20-25mil. Does the width of the power line vary with the specific magnitude of current or just make it as wide as possible?
- Due to little component, is it necessary to make lines except power wider?
- Are there other mistakes in layout and routing?

---

Update PCB with labels.

[image]

Comment: Have you run any checks in your layout tool? What checks? What limits does the checker use?

Comment: Please draw your decoupling capacitors next to their respective IC. How come you are not using a ground plane?

Comment: I have drawn the decoupling capacitors next to their respective IC.I will add polygon to GND as everything seems good.

Comment: What's "lora"? If it's a wireless module, then it possibly has an area under which you mustn't put *Anything*, often not even ground plane.

Comment: @Marcus Müller yes,it's an integrated wireless module,and the antenna is integrated on the module.I put LoRa at the back,Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: my take on your pcb]
I would move the component with the light-green arrow and in dark-green I have added my take on cleaner routing.

Set a rule to have thermal reliefs of atleast 10mil, altough I use 20mil when possible.
Add teardrops (Tools->Add teardrops).

You also need to add a Polygon and connect that to GND. For best practice, add the polygon on the top and bottom. Repour the polygon after selecting the correct net.

In the schematic I don't see any weird things.

Comment: some dark-green lines are right angle,isn't it not recommended for use?

Comment: @user7476499:  [There's nothing wrong with 90 degree angles.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/226693/47070)

Answer (score 1):

> Could you help check any mistakes in my PCB layout and routing?

No, can't check that  none of the parts on the red side are labeled.

but you should keep everything away from the antenna area, ideally even the board.

Some parts seem to have too few connections.
some of the joins between traces are too sharp
Other than that it's hard to say.

Comment: I have update the PCB with lable,anything wrong in layout?https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTjWL.jpg